# How to validate a bitcoin address

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am looking for a method of validating a bitcoin address which does:

- Bitcoin addresses of different lengths (as they vary)
- Validation through the hash of the address (which I believe is how it's done)

I am looking for ideally sample code or an open source project as I have found neither so far in C#.

Comment: Well a simple search brought the following : https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Address#Address_validation

Comment: @Aybe I had seen that - which leads to some Python but I am really after an existing C# project.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a C# library for validating bitcoin addresses here :

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoin_Address_Utility

https://github.com/casascius/Bitcoin-Address-Utility

Comment: Perfect, that's what I was after, thanks :)